# How to choose the queue for Spark job using spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is there a way to provide parameters or settings to choose the queue in which I'd like my spark_submit job to run?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By using --queue  
So an example of a spark-submit job would be:-

> spark-submit --master yarn --conf spark.executor.memory=48G --conf spark.driver.memory=6G --packages [packages separated by ,] --queue [queue_name] --class [class_name] [jar_file] [arguments]