# hadoop cluster + any way to disable spark application to run on specific data nodes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, ambari, hdp, datanode

we have Hadoop cluster ( `HDP 2.6.5` cluster with ambari , with 25 datanodes machines )

we are using spark streaming application (`spark 2.1` run over `Hortonworks 2.6.x` )

the current situation is that spark streaming applications runs on all datanodes machines

but now we want the spark streaming application to run only on the first `10 datanodes` machines

so the others last `15 datanodes` machines will be restricted , and spark application will runs only on the first `10 datanodes` machines

is this scenario can be done by ambary features or other approach?

for example we found the - https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/configuring_node_labels.html ,

and

http://crazyadmins.com/configure-node-labels-on-yarn/

but not sure if Node Labes can help us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jessica  Yes, you are absolutely onto the right path.  Yarn Node Labels and Yarn Queues are how Ambari Administrators control team level access to portions of the entire yarn cluster.  You can start very basic with just a non default queues or get very in-depth with many queues for many different teams.  Node labels take it to another level, allow you to map queues and teams to nodes specifically.

Here is a post with the syntax for spark to use the yarn queue:

[How to choose the queue for Spark job using spark-submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551337/how-to-choose-the-queue-for-spark-job-using-spark-submit)

I tried to find 2.6 version of these docs, but was not able....  they have really mixed up the docs since the merger...

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/ch_node_labels.html

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-operating-system/content/configuring_node_labels.html

The actual steps you may have to take may be a combination of items from both.   Typical experience for me when working in Ambari HDP/HDF.

Comment: - Since I am using spark 2.1
I found that my spark version support the following parameters - spark.yarn.am.nodeLabelExpression to restrict AppMaster node placement, and spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression for executor placement.

The question is – how to set this parameters with which values and in my case I am using ambari then when to set these parameters?  ( +1 for your answer )

Comment: You may want to play with a test cluster first because you will need to change and restart a lot of services,  but you need to start with yarn queue and node label configs, Ambari has a UI View for this.  Get that all sorted, then start playing with spark config to use the nodes you labeled for the parameters you reference.  Also maybe just test the actual spark jobs with the --queue command.   Most developers prefer to control it at the application level for example, they may use 1 queue for dev testing, and another queue for scaled testing...